# C# create multiple instances of nested controls

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, runtime

I have a tabbed interface - where the tabs will contain multiple nested controls.  In particular, Panels containing panels, containing Grids, etc. Even in some cases additional Tab controls.  (Yes it can be a little messy)

However, now I need to create some of these tabs dynamically at run time - and still reference the controls on them.  So - for example lets say I have something like

Tab

Panel

TabControl

Tab

Grid

Graph/Chart

Panel

Buttons

I need to create multiple new tabs for each result DataTable I need to display(I do not know how many I have to create until Run Time - or I would just do this all at Design time).

I understand I will create these controls at RunTime - and I can do it easily for one additional instance - but then I start running into naming issues.   I cannot add three GridControls (all called DataGrid) to the same form - and because C# is strongly typed I cannot create the variable names at Runtime.  AND I also need to be able to reference these controls at some times.

So - I looking for possible solutions.  I could create arrays for each type of control I am hoping to create.  There are over 15 controls (some nested) for each tab - so it could get a little messy.  But it would allow me to access each control - as I could use the Tag Property of the Tab page to allow me to access the various arrays.  If I created the arrays to hold a max of 50 elements - it should be more than enough (I do not see users creating more then 5 or 10 of these extra tabs).

As I am somewhat new to C# and Visual Studio - I am wondering how others would handle this sort of task?  How would you go about creating multiple instances of embedded (nested) controls on your form - knowing that you will have to reference them elsewhere in the code??

Any thoughts and pointers would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Bradley

Comment: Perhaps look into the `UserControl` and please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: If you create them at design time you would give them meaningful names so you can access them later via that name. If you create them at runtime, the same rule applies. I am Not sure what you are having issues with.

Comment: It appears you're using WinForms, but neither your question nor its tags mention it directly. Please add the appropriate tags to specify.

Comment: CodingYoshi - maybe I am missing something?  But since I do not know how many tabs I will have - how do you create a variable name like Grid1, Grid2, ... GridN - when you do not know how many instances you will have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's an arbitrary amount of tabs, you'll need to manage them programmatically.

> So - I looking for possible solutions. I could create arrays for each type of control I am hoping to create. There are over 15 controls (some nested) for each tab - so it could get a little messy. But it would allow me to access each control - as I could use the Tag Property of the Tab page to allow me to access the various arrays. If I created the arrays to hold a max of 50 elements - it should be more than enough (I do not see users creating more then 5 or 10 of these extra tabs).

That would indeed become messy, and is a recipe for bugs. `Tag` is a very useful property in the right circumstances, but generally you should avoid using it unless you have a good reason. You might inadvertently introduce cyclic references that leak memory. I find it's most suited for storing related metadata such as an ID(however, avoid storing value types in it, as they become [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)).

If you haven't already, I suggest adopting the same naming convention you use with variables for the names you set in the designer. As backing variables reflect those names, it should help you avoid name conflicts with properties, and keep your code more consistent. My team and I use the convention `mSomeField` for private fields and designer set names and it has served us well in avoiding most name conflicts over the years.

Start by designing a new `UserControl` that will serve as the content of the most common tab category, adding as much common layout as possible. Design additional `UserControl`s for each additional tab category. Add accessors for each nested control you need to expose.

Note that the following code uses some C#6/7 features.

In practice, here's what that could look like:

```
// Code-behind for the UserControl representing the content of the 1st tab category.
class Cat1TabContent : UserControl
{
    //...
    // These all refer to controls created and named from the designer.
    public Panel PrimaryPanel => primaryPanel;
    public TabControl TabManager => tabManager;
    public Panel SecondaryPanel => secondaryPanel;
    //...
}
```

Managing tabs(in the main form and all other controls that have a TabControl):

```
//...
private List<UserControl> tabContents = new List<UserControl>();

void AddTab<T>() where T : UserControl, new()
{
    var tab = new TabPage();
    var tabContent = new T();
    tabContents.Add(tabContent);
    tab.Controls.Add(tabContent);
    tabControl.Controls.Add(tab);
}

void RemoveTab(TabPage tab)
{
    if (tab == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tab));

    if (tab.Controls.Count != 0 && tab.Controls[0] is UserControl tabContent) {
        tabContents.Remove(tabContent);
    }
    tabControl.Controls.Remove(tab);
}
//...
```

Accessing nested controls:

```
// Form >> Tab Control >> 1st Tab >> 1st Child.
// This assumes AddTab<Cat1Content>() was called.
var firstContent = (Cat1Content)tabContents[0];

// Content >> PrimaryPanel; Enumerates over nested controls.
foreach (var child in firstContent.PrimaryPanel.Controls) {
    // ...
}

// Content >> Tab Control; Enumerates over nested tabs. 
foreach (var child in firstContent.TabManager.Controls) {
    // This is safe, TabControl throws an exception if you try to add anything that isn't a TabPage.
    var tab = (TabPage)child;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Koby - thank you.  I have a lot to learn about UserControls apparently.  This was exactly what I was looking for.    
do you know if it is it possible to directly access a subcontrol?  Something like Cat1TabContent.Grid  or Cat1TabContent.TabPages[I].Grid, etc??

Comment: It would seem that this is the answer:  
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/141469/how-to-access-child-control-of-a-user-control

Comment: @user7003495 `TabPage` doesn't have a `Grid` property, but you could create a subclass that does. Without adding more API layers, you'll have to access the content of each `TabPage` and extract the controls you're interested in. i.e. `((Cat1TabContent)TabPages[i].Controls[0]).PrimaryPanel`.